# Python turtle graphics filling issue

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm supposed to draw a building for my Python class, and the `fillcolor()` function does its job for two of the shapes, but for the last shape, even though I finish the circuit so to speak, it won't fill it with the color I need:

```
import turtle

def main():
    turtle.setup(900, 900)
    cityscape(-300, -400, 300, 'gray')
    cityscape(0, -400, 300, 'gray')
    building(-300, -100, 'gray')
    turtle.speed(0)

def cityscape(x, y, width, color):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    turtle.pencolor('gray')
    turtle.fillcolor(color)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.begin_fill()
    for count in range(4):
        turtle.forward(width)
        turtle.left(90)
    turtle.end_fill()

def building(x, y, color):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    turtle.fillcolor(color)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.right(180)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(200)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(250)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(70)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(175)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(80)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(70)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(425)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(425)


main()
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You left `turtle.end_fill()` off the end of your `building()` function.  I'd also write `main()` as follows:

```
def main():
    turtle.setup(900, 900)
    turtle.speed('fastest')
    cityscape(-300, -400, 300, 'gray')
    cityscape(0, -400, 300, 'gray')
    building(-300, -100, 'gray')
    turtle.mainloop()
```

Complete code listing with the above fix and some style changes:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def main():
    screen = Screen()
    screen.setup(900, 900)

    yertle = Turtle(visible=False)
    yertle.speed('fastest')

    cityscape(yertle, -300, -400, 300, 'gray')
    cityscape(yertle, 0, -400, 300, 'gray')
    building(yertle, -300, -100, 'gray')

    screen.mainloop()

def cityscape(turtle, x, y, width, color):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    turtle.pendown()

    turtle.color(color)

    turtle.begin_fill()
    for _ in range(4):
        turtle.forward(width)
        turtle.left(90)
    turtle.end_fill()

def building(turtle, x, y, color):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    turtle.pendown()

    turtle.color(color)

    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(200)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(250)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(70)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(175)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(80)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(70)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(425)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(425)
    turtle.end_fill()

main()
```

Comment: So you're saying I need to place my end fill under def building instead of cityscape

Comment: @DonniBenotti, no, I'm saying you need one `end_fill()` for every `begin_fill()`.  I'm adding a complete code listing to my answer.

Comment: I misread that entirely the first time, I was a little stressed, but it worked out. thanks for your help. It turned out well in the end.